# How long does it take for Ajax success function to wait a response from the server?

Tags: node.js, ajax

When making Ajax call to an API which fetches data from db and returns response back to the callback function of the Ajax call made.

1. How much time does it take for this callback function to wait for a response 
   from the API which fetches data from db ?
2. Is there a way of increasing this time of waiting for a response by the 
   callback function of the Ajax call made?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can customise the timeout for the request.
Assuming, you are using jQuery. If not, you can customise timeout for raw XHR request as well, just google out the syntax

Below is an example, of how to do it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/url/to/the/endpoint",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached, or server responded with error status code
    },
    success: function(){
        //will fire when 200 success was received from the server
    },
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3000 milliseconds, You can change according to your need
});
```

Hope it helps!